# Django Queryset: iterate through nested array of objects in JSONField using annotation and F expressions

Tags: arrays, json, django, postgresql

In my Django 4.2 project, I have a model with some `JSONField` (using PgSQL and the DB backend), e.g.

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

And model instances contain nested arrays of JSON objects, e.g.

```
{
  "members":[
    {
      "name": "Person #1",
      "age": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Person #2",
      "age": 51
    }
  ],
  "other_data": ...
}
```

While obtaining `MyModel` instances from the DB, I'd like to simplify the content to be returned later in the View, so that I don't return complete array of `members` objects (for each model instance) but only an array of string (their `name`s). I.e. instead of returning content like:

```
  [
    {
      "members":[
        {
          "name": "Person #1.1",
          "age": 41
        },
        {
          "name": "Person #1.2",
          "age": 51
        }
      ],
      "other_data": ...
    },
    {
      "members":[
        {
          "name": "Person #2.1",
          "age": 42
        },
        {
          "name": "Person #2.2",
          "age": 52
        }
      ],
      "other_data": ...
    },
    ...
  ]
```

I'd actually like to return:

```
  [
    {
      "member_names":["Person #1.1", "Person #1.2"],
      "other_data": ...
    },
    {
      "member_names":["Person #2.1", "Person #2.2"],
      "other_data": ...
    },
    ...
  ]
```

I'd like to use Django queryset annotation to introduce `member_names` property above, which would summarize the `name` properties from related `members` array (of each model instance). Annotation approach works well for non-iterative JSON structures (i.e. objects in objects in objects), but I'm having problems to handle iterative structures like the one above.

Anyone ever implemented something similar?

Example #1: The following code in the View:

```
results = list(MyModel.objects.annotate(member_names=F("members__name")).values('member_names', 'other_data'))
```

produces the following:

```
  [
    {
      "member_names": null,
      "other_data": ...
    },
    {
      "member_names": null,
      "other_data": ...
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Example #2: The following code in the View:

```
results = list(MyModel.objects.annotate(member_names=F("members__0__name")).values('member_names', 'other_data'))
```

produces the following result:

```
  [
    {
      "member_names": "Person #1.1",
      "other_data": ...
    },
    {
      "member_names": "Person #2.1",
      "other_data": ...
    },
    ...
  ]
```

I was also looking into some aggregation-related methods, but I don't need to get a plain piece of data based on an array; I need an array based on the array.

There are also many ways to iterate through results upon obtaining those form the DB. There are also ways to do this via raw SQL query and some PgSQL-specific functions like `json_array_elements`. But I'd like to stay with Django ORM and be as efficient as possible (avoiding to traverse the queryset offline, manually).

Comment: A database should *not* be optimized on how you show data to the outside world. Especially if the data has a *fixed* structure, a JSON field is a (very) bad idea, since it does not comply with 1NF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thanks for the input @WillemVanOnsem but it doesn't help answering the problem described above.

Comment: @MarkoAdrijevic: no, but the modeling should be fixed first, otherwise all filtering, serializing, etc. will all eventually hit the same problem.

Comment: But this is just an example, trivial code snippet. Do you think described problem can never occur in the real life? And instead of proposing the solution, we should try to avoid getting into the described situation?